# Rendering a shared texture in DirectX 11 only shows black

Tags: hlsl, directx-11, texture2d, render-to-texture

I'm trying to use a texture to share rendered surfaces between 2 different applications.  Everything appears to work correctly, except that when sampling the shared texture I only ever receive black.

1) First, I create a shared texture as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554(v=vs.85).aspx.  The source application successfully supplies the destination application with the handle of teh shared resource, the resource is opened and a resource view is created happily.

```
(src Application)
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC SharedTextureDesc = TextureDesc;
SharedTextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
SharedTextureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX;
hResult = pD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&SharedTextureDesc, NULL, &m_pSharedRenderBuffer);

(dstApplication)
HANDLE hSharedRenderHandle = pDisplayCallback->GetSharedRenderBuffer();
hr = pDevice->OpenSharedResource( hSharedRenderHandle,__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*) &m_pSharedRenderTexture);
pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(m_pSharedRenderTexture, NULL, &m_RenderTextureView);

// Create the sample state
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
ZeroMemory( &sampDesc, sizeof(sampDesc) );
sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
sampDesc.MinLOD = -FLT_MAX;
sampDesc.MaxLOD = FLT_MAX;
hr = pDevice->CreateSamplerState( &sampDesc, &m_TexSamplerState );
```

2) At the end of the Source application render, I copy the back buffer to the shared render texture.

```
(acquireSync)
pDeviceContext->CopyResource(pContext->m_pSharedRenderBuffer, pContext->m_pBackBuffer);
(releaseSync)
```

3) During the destination render, at a certain point I render out a full screen quad with the contents of the original render.

```
// Set the sampler state in the pixel shader.
pContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_TexSamplerState);
pContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_RenderTextureView);
```

4) The VS shader creates the full screen quad, and the PS shader simply sets the color according to the texture value

VS (described here: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/08/08/interesting-vertex-shader-trick/)

```
VS_Output Output;
Output.Tex = float2((id << 1) & 2, id & 2);
Output.Pos = float4(Output.Tex * float2(2,-2) + float2(-1,1), 0, 1);
return Output;
```

PS (for debugging I set a portion of the screen to UV's, and the rest to texture)

```
float4 DiffuseColor = float4(vsIn.Tex.x, vsIn.Tex.y, 0, 1);
if (vsIn.Tex.x > 0.5 || vsIn.Tex.y < 0.5)
    DiffuseColor = g_RenderBuffer.Sample(g_Sampler, vsIn.Tex);
return DiffuseColor;
```

Theoretically, this is all I need.  However, things get weird.

The render is happening correctly, the full screen is rendered according to the output of my PixelShader.

My UV's are correct, because rendering them gives about what you'd expect.

I have tried loading a texture from disk and rendering that directly.  This works fine.

I have tried writing my shared buffer to disk, to ensure that what I am recieving has some values set - this also works.

I've tried comparing the descriptions for the shared texture/view vs the working disk-based texture/view, and they seem similar.  Only difference I can see are the lack of miplevels on the shared texture, which is fine, I don't want mip levels, and shared texture format matches source buffer render surface: DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB (loaded texture is BC3_UNORM)

The syncing seems to be fine, or at least when I first tried this several days ago D3D threw warnings that the resource was not sync'ed, and I fixed that.

According to everything, everything is working, its just that the texture is black according to D3D!

Any thoughts?  I'm not a graphics programmer by any stretch, so debugging this issue has been a lot of fun so far!  Last notes - I can't attach Pix or use VS2012 gfx debugging, as it crashes on app start.

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug layers?  Call `D3D11CreateDevice` with the [D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107(v=vs.85).aspx) flag on both processes' devices. Any warnings or errors will appear in debug output.

Comment: I've tried forcing the processes into Debug mode using the DirectX Control Panel, but I don't receive any messages about this operation.  I believe I have built this correctly because I receive warnings about empty vertex buffers etc.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out to be that AcquireSync() just timed out (after 5ms) and I actually didn't have access to the texture. Please check you AcquireSync() call (e.g use 5000ms) to use if it's timing out or returning properly. So try AcquireSync(0, 5000). It helped me to figure out the problem.